# xpath in vb.net not selecting nodes with 2 criteria

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to 'drill down' to the info that I want from this [xml](http://tatts.com/pagedata/racing/2011/10/5/BR.xml).

This 'query' returns the correct nodes (6):

> nodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/RaceDay/Meeting/Race[@RaceNo=" & "1" &
>   "]/Pool")

This one doesn't return anything:

> nodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/RaceDay/Meeting/Race[@RaceNo=" & "1" &
>   "]/Pool[@PoolType=" & "A2" & "]")

Can I use 2 values for different nodes or more to simply pinpoint the node that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer is yes. You can filter the nodes by the attributes of the elements to your hearts content. The reason the first query works is that it is a numeric value, the second query didn't work because the value is a string so "A2" wount work, but "'A2'" WILL !

```
nodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/RaceDay/Meeting/Race[@RaceNo=" & "1" & "]/Pool[@PoolType=" & "'A2'" & "]")
```